# CI Controller Method Calling issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, php-7

I am having a strange problem with Codeigniter in Function calling. I created a controller name **ErrorLog** and then create a method **addUpdateError**. Then at view part I have created a Link (anchor tag) like this

```
<a style="float:right" href="<?php echo site_url('errorLog/addUpdateError') ?>" title="Add an Error" alt="Add an Error">Add an Error</a>
```

I even try this

```
<a style="float:right" href="errorLog/addUpdateError" title="Add an Error" alt="Add an Error">Add an Error</a>
```

And this one also

```
<a style="float:right" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>errorLog/addUpdateError" title="Add an Error" alt="Add an Error">Add an Error</a>
```

URL in browser is **http://localhost/projectName/errorLog/addUpdateError**  and I think it is valid.

When I hit this anchor tag it gives me this error

[image]

The default controller is loading properly but after that if I navigate to anywhere it is not working. I have correctly setup my **base_url** in **config.php** and I also set **index_page** to blank. I have tried all possible ways and search all over Google.
I even tried with Codeigniter fresh setup with **CodeIgniter-2.2.6** in **Welcome controller** the issue is still appearing.

Currently I am using **PHP 7 and COdeigniter 3 and Ubuntu 16.04** I am just guessing may be this issue is because of **PHP 7**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you updated your  DB driver from `mysql` to `mysqli` ?

Comment: Ya I did it but I am not performing DB operation now just simple clicking is causing problem.

Comment: try with index.php may be .htacess is not working. try this url :- http://localhost/projectName/index.php/errorLog/addUpdateError

Comment: @Bhavin Thanks Buddy as of now it is working but what if I want to remove index.php from URL. May issue may come again.

Comment: you have to change .htaccess file for removing index.php file from url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to .htaccess file.

Try following step,

set config file (`application/config/config.php`) like this,

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

After that, change your .htaccess file which is located your project root folder not in the application folder with the following code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I also tried the same pattern but don't know what happed may be there was some problem in my htaccess file.

Comment: yeah sometimes it happens. Happy coding. :)